# Snowpipe for continuous ingestion of daily files arriving irregularly

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and we are working on a POC. The scenario is we get around 100 (.txt) files from our ERP system uploaded into S3 bucket overnight. We would need these files to be loaded into Staging tables and then to DW tables, with data transformations applied, in snowflake. We are thinking of using snowpipe to load the data from S3 to the staging tables as file arrival from ERP is not scheduled and could be anytime within a window of four hours. The daily files are timestamped and will have full data daily. So we would need the staging tables to be truncated daily before ingesting the day's file.

But snow-pipe definition doesn't allow truncate/create statements.

Please share your thoughts on this. Should we continue considering snow-pipe? or try using COPY command scheduled as a 'TASK' to run at fixed intervals, say for every 15 minutes?

Comment: Rather than a task that runs every 15mins, why not run a daily task that truncates the table and let snowpipe copy in?

Comment: You can create stored proc to execute as a separate  before your data load kicks in a task.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Got the point on using a scheduled task to truncate all the staging tables before the ETL kicks in for the day. But we are also planning to use Streams on staging tables for CDC to identify delta load to be upserted into the 'DW' tables. Is it possible to utilize Streams in this case? Please share your thoughts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just continually adding the data to your stage tables, put an append-only `STREAM` over that table, and then use tasks to load downstream tables from the `STREAM`.  The task could run every minute with a `WHEN` statement that checks whether data is in the `STREAM` or not.  This would load the data and push it downstream whenever the data happens to land from your ERP.

Then, you can have a daily task that runs anytime during the day which checks the `STREAM` to make sure there is NO DATA in it, and if that's true, then `DELETE` everything in the underlying table.  This step only needs to happen to save storage and because the `STREAM` is append-only, the `DELETE` statement does not create records in your `STREAM`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. To elaborate a bit on the use case, the daily files from ERP are  full data downloads with 'datetime' suffixed to the file names. Snowpipe will treat each day's files as new files and will 'COPY' the data into staging tables. This makes truncation of staging tables before each day's data refresh imperative. We are planning to use Streams upon staging tables to capture the changed data to be upserted into the DW tables. Is it possible to use 'Streams' in this scenario. Please share your thoughts on this. Thank you!

Comment: If you reference the Streams, then it becomes less critical to truncate the tables before the process begins.  You can do it at any time.  An append-only stream won't reflect deletes that occur on the table underneath.  You could literally do the truncate on a weekly basis and it won't matter to your downstream processes, since the stream will only ever reference the data that has been loaded since the last time your process ran.

Comment: Thank you @Mike walton.

Comment: Thank you @Mike. We get full data files each day and truncation notwithstanding, Streams will not be able to capture the delta as its full load daily and we might have to go with full table scan or source key identifier based change capture for CDC and then use Merge to persist the changes in DW layer. Please correct me if something is amiss in my understanding here.

Comment: If you insert a full load of data into a table daily and have a stream over it, the stream will only ever contain that 1 day's full load.